# Docusign Api is not working

Tags: php

I have used this API code. It Shows an error "error calling webservice, status is:0". 
I want to add Docusign in my website, but unable to do.

```
<?php

// Input your info here:
$email = "***";         // your account email (also where this signature request will be sent)
$password = "****";     // your account password
$integratorKey = "***";     // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
$recipientName = "***";     // provide a recipient (signer) name
$templateId = "***";        // provide a valid templateId of a template in your account
$templateRoleName = "***";  // use same role name that exists on the template in the console

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

// --- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create and envelope using one template role (called "Signer1") and one recipient
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template",
    "templateId" => $templateId, 
    "templateRoles" => array( 
            array( "email" => $email, "name" => $recipientName, "roleName" => $templateRoleName )),
    "status" => "sent");                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

// --- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n"; 
?>
```

Please any one can help me, with the process. I search all API but shows same error.

Comment: Seems like a server restriction issue to me

Comment: Which type of server restriction issue? Am i using the right code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line given below

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

after this line `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));` Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for your support Sir. Can you tell me something, how can I integrate docusign in my website. I want to set a sign box in my document that is generated after filling a form.After submitting this form is generated in pdf.